# 2 column list in Latex

Tags: latex

I have a list, and each item of the list has a header and content, the content can be large so it can wrap. I need to show the list in form of 2 columns. For example :-

- Heading 1     Content 1
- Heading 2     Content 2
                     Wraped content 2

Comment: Okay, however I don't see a programming question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to use a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
\textbullet~Heading 1 & Content 1\\
\textbullet~Heading 2 & Content 2 which is so long that it continues in the next line but needs to be longer to break\newline  Wraped content 2\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]